# backbone.js + global event dispatcher + require.js: how-to?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, eventaggregator

I have a number of backbone models, organized in collections and connected to their corresponding views and/or collections of views. Some of these models that do not belong to the same collection need to trigger an event which is of interest to another model (and maybe more than one).

The recommended way to deal with this is, I think, the "global event dispatcher/aggregator" as described [here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/) and other places.

However, I also happen to be using require.js, which seems to go against the idea of attaching the dispatcher/aggregator to the application's namespace object -- or am I wrong here?

So my question is: using require.js how can I have a number of different backbone models trigger an event that will be handled by another model?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A similar solution to what @Andreas proposed but without Backbone.Marionette (heavily inspired nonetheless, [see the article linked in the question](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/)).

All you have to do is to define a module that creates a singleton of an event listener and require this object in the modules where you want to trigger an event or listen to this event.

Let's say you have *app/channel.js* defining your channel

```
define(['backbone', 'underscore'], function (Backbone, _) {
    var channel = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events); 
    return channel;
});
```

You can then use it as a *listener* via

```
require(['app/channel'], function (channel) {
    channel.on('app.event', function () {
        console.log('app.event');
    });
});
```

and you can trigger an event on this channel via

```
require(['app/channel'], function (channel) {
    channel.trigger('app.event');
});
```

Comment: I think that this is what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot nikoshr and andreas

Comment: What is the advantage of event usage in this situation? We still have to include "app/model" in all modules where we going to trigger that event. Why not to make an api call on that model?

Comment: @wizardzloy The only module you have to include is `app/channel` where you want to listen to or trigger a global event. `app/model` is only there to demonstrate a sample usage.

Comment: @wizardzloy But I admit the examples might be confusing. I tried to reword my answer a bit, I hope it's clearer.

Comment: @nikoshr But if we won't include the "app/model" that script won't be loaded at all. So we still have to include it somewhere

Comment: @wizardzloy You lost me. The question was about a global event handler and I hope my answer does address that. `app/model` was used as a (contrived and not very useful, indeed) demo and is now removed.

Comment: I think you should include underscore as well to get access to _.extend.

Answer (score 1):

We using Marionettes `app.vent` (which is the global event transmitter for our application), allong with require js and it works really well.

**app**

```
define(, function(){
  return new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
})
```

**Model1**

```
define(['app'], function(app){
  return Backbone.Marionette.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
      this.bindTo('app.vent', 'create:model2', this.toSomething, this);
    }
  })
})
```

**Model2**

```
define(['app'], function(app){
  return Backbone.Marionette.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
      app.vent.trigger('create:model2', this);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Good to know that Marionette is OK with require.js. However is there no solution to the problem that doesn't involve an additional / alternative framework?

Comment: There are a bunch of solutions. I can advice PubSubJS: https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a look at it. But are there no solutions that do not involve _any_ additional framework?

Comment: There is no such thing in requirejs, so you have to use an additional framework or write by yourself.